# Unable to send two strings together using PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, string

I'm trying to pass database value javascript / ajax. If if send directly it works well,

The same I'm trying to do from database. And some how it doesn't work.

I'm sending value of the option to script like this,

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
```

and when I send value directly like this, It show the correct value in script.

```
<option value="Peter Grif">Peter Griffin</option>
```

Script Result is = Peter Grif

And if the same I fetch from database, like this.

```
while($row=$select->fetch_assoc())
         {
            echo "<option value=".$row['name'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
         }
```

In Dropdown box it is exactly working with full name like "Peter Grif"

But the script result is = "Peter" the second part of name after space never comes.

Full Program:

```
  <html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    window.alert(str);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body>

<form>


    <center> <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)"> </center>

    <option value="Peter Grif">Peter Griffin</option>
    <option value="Lois Griff">Lois Griffin</option>

        <?php
             include("connection.php");
             $select=$con->query("select name from users group by name");

             while($row=$select->fetch_assoc())
             {
                echo "<option value=".$row['name'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
             }

        ?>  

    </select> 

</form>

<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo "<option value="'.$row['name'].'">".$row['name']."</option>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code in while loop and it works as you want. Its the quotation issue.

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
        window.alert(str);

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body>

    <form>


        <center> <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)"> </center>

        <option value="Peter Grif">Peter Griffin</option>
        <option value="Lois Griff">Lois Griffin</option>

            <?php
                 include("connection.php");
                 $select=$con->query("select name from users group by name");

                 while($row=$select->fetch_assoc())
                 {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                 }

            ?>  

        </select> 

    </form>

    <br>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Wow!! Great It worked.  I wasted 3 hours for this :(  Thanks dude

Comment: you are welcome. Please mark it as a right one. I will get some point or give it a marks. :D :D ,anyway you are welsome

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option value=".$row['name'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
```

The option value needs to be quoted.  You are ending up with

```
<option value=Peter Grif>Peter Grif</option>
```

It needs to be quoted so it ends up like

```
<option value='Peter Grif'>Peter Grif</option>
```

So either

```
    echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
```

or perhaps

```
    echo "<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
```

(you can reference arrays within double quotes by surrounding by curly brackets, I feel it makes it easier to read than concatenation, so you don't get quote confused when echoing HTML especially, but it's just my preference).

Doing view source on page can help with these things to make sure the generated HTML is valid.